# Como passar uma lista de objetos para um form e retorna-la para o main

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, winforms

Eu instanciei uma lista de objetos no main onde tbm instanciei os forms, queria passar essa lista de objetos para o form onde ele vai pegar um user e uma senha e criar e instancia um objeto e adiciona-lo a lista qnd o botão registrar for clicado.

```
static void Main()
    {
        List <User> usuarios = new List <User> ();
        ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
        Application.Run(new loginRegister(usuarios));
    }
```

eu to tentando passar a lista para o form e fazer alterações nessa lista

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

Para passar uma lista de objetos para um formulário no C#, você pode passá-la como um parâmetro no construtor do formulário.

Por exemplo, você pode alterar o construtor do seu formulário loginRegister para receber uma lista de User como parâmetro:

```
public loginRegister(List<User> usuarios)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.usuarios = usuarios;
}
```

Então, no seu método Main, basta passar a lista como parâmetro ao instanciar o formulário:

```
static void Main()
{
    List<User> usuarios = new List<User>();
    ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
    Application.Run(new loginRegister(usuarios));
}
```

Dessa forma, você pode acessar e alterar a lista de User no formulário loginRegister usando a variável usuarios.

Para adicionar um novo objeto User à lista, basta chamar o método Add da lista:

```
usuarios.Add(novoUsuario);
```